# Oracle: date to half-year

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-conversion

What I need is a conversion from a date to the half-year:

- 29.06.2018  ->  1
- 01.05.2018  ->  1
- 01.07.2018  ->  2
- 15.10.2018  ->  2

I did not find anything like that here [Round and Truncate in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084)

So, no built-in function exists indeed? I'm quite perplexed because that's not a very rare use case. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Oracle's in-built format masks only go down as far as quarters (e.g. `to_char(sysdate, 'Q')`. You say going to half-years is not very rare? I've never needed to do it in the nearly 20 years I've been working with Oracle SQL, fwiw!

Comment: why not `TRUNC(to_char(sysdate, 'Q')/2)`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think you mean `CEIL` rather than `TRUNC`

Comment: Of course it must be CEIL

Comment: However, I read that it's not very efficient to convert a date to VARCHAR2 and then to convert it to number again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when extract(month from datecol) <= 6 then 1
             else 2
        end) as half_year
```

Comment: Thank you! It's very easy indeed. You forgot the parenthesis around the expression: extract (month from datecol) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple arithmetic:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM somedate)-1)/6+1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `EXTRACT()`:

```
SELECT CEIL(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM mydate)/6)
  FROM mytable;
```